# Why would the same command produce different output when executed in Terminal vs. SSH

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

Apparently, this is a thing and I'd like to know why. I noticed this when I was trying to install the `gitlab-runner` CI client on an M1 Mac Mini running macOS 12.1 over SSH. I was following the instructions and eventually got to one command that wouldn't run.

Eventually, it turned out that the same command,

```
gitlab-runner start
```

produced a completely different error message when run in Terminal and over SSH:

```
FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: *launchctl* failed with stderr: Load failed: 5: input/output error
Try running 'launchctl bootstrap' as root for richer errors.
```

vs

```
FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: exit status 134
```

It seems like the entire extended error message about `launchctl` somehow got contracted to just `exit status 134` over SSH.

While digging through the Net for a solution to my problem, I happened across several other people mentioning the issue, but no explanation as to why.

Comment: Did you grant Full Disk Access to all commands involved? Do you run these jobs as a standard or an admin user?

Comment: Re: Full Disk Access, I don't have physical access to the machine right now but one thread on the Apple Dev Forums suggested trying to access `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`, which does work over SSH, suggesting that FDA is enabled. The user in question is an admin user.